# How to omit base name in find output?

Tags: bash

```
find . -maxdepth 1
```

how to omit `./` current directory prefix from the output?

Also is there any way to `ls` the output separated by newlines **AND** containing only file/dir name field(e.g. no file attributes), like this

```
file1.txt
dir1
file2.txt
dir2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ls -1` to get the output you want from `ls`.  From the [`ls(1)` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls):

```
   -1     list one file per line
```

The `-1` format is also the default when the output of `ls` isn't a terminal.

To strip the `./` from `find`, I'd just do:

```
find . | cut -c 3-
```

Comment: Just to let you guys know that all answers are acceptable (except the one from Perry).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec basename {} \;
```

`basename` does exactly what you need, and `-exec` calls it for every match.

Comment: also need files, not only dirs, so omiting -type is what I want.

Comment: sorry, a bit sleepy. changed it

Answer (score 1):

About `ls`.  If you only want the names with no attributes you may use `-1` switch, as in

```
ls -1
```

Because `ls` is often aliased in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, from the terminal, prepend the command with back slash `\` to override the alias

```
\ls -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can arbitrarily postprocess the output of find using tools like sed(1) and awk(1). That would probably be the easiest way to accomplish your overall goal.

For example, you can remove the leading part of each line with

find ... | sed -e 's/^.\///'

You can similarly use a regular expression based match to split the dir name from the file name and place them on distinct lines.

Comment: I was hoping there will be shorter way without postprocessing, at least for `find`

Comment: The whole point of the unix toolset is to put together chains of commands, each of which does one thing in a simple way, to achieve goals like this. People do keep adding random command line switches to various tools to add more and more options, but an infinite number of options exists in the programmability of the tools and the ability to chain them together with pipelines. That's the whole point of Unix.

Comment: I understand, but the example you brought was not working. `Unknown option  to s`

Comment: The backslash you need before the slash to quote it got eaten by the markup language. I've quoted the backslash (ick) and now it is visible. However, if you didn't catch that on your own, it means you don't know how to use regular expressions for rewriting strings -- and you very uch should...

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
(cd path/to; find . -maxdepth 1 | cut -c 3- | tail -n+2)
```

which is likely equivalent to

```
ls -al1 path/to | tail -n+3
```

Because given

```
mkdir lookhere
touch lookhere/{.a,b.file,c}
```

Then this diff will be empty

```
diff <(cd lookhere; find . -maxdepth 1 | cut -c 3- | tail -n+2) <(ls -al1 lookhere/ | tail -n+3)
```

i.e. both produce the output

```
.a
b.file
c
```